# Calling flatten on a hash in ruby. Oddities

Tags: ruby

Say I have the following hash:

```
error_hash = {
    :base => [
        [0] [
            [0] "Address is required to activate"
        ]
    ]
}
```

Are these results odd?

```
[18] pry(#<Api::UsersController>)> error_hash.flatten
[
    [0] :base,
    [1] [
        [0] [
            [0] "Address is required to activate"
        ]
    ]
]
[19] pry(#<Api::UsersController>)> error_hash.flatten(1)
[
    [0] :base,
    [1] [
        [0] [
            [0] "Address is required to activate"
        ]
    ]
]
[20] pry(#<Api::UsersController>)> error_hash.flatten(2)
[
    [0] :base,
    [1] [
        [0] "Address is required to activate"
    ]
]
[21] pry(#<Api::UsersController>)> error_hash.flatten(3)
[
    [0] :base,
    [1] "Address is required to activate"
]
```

I would have expected `.flatten` to have been equal to `flatten(3)`, or in otherwords, I would have expected `.flatten` to have flattened recursively until evereything was in a single array.

Comment: @Richard, that question concerns [Array#flatten](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-flatten); this one, [Hash#flatten](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-flatten).

Comment: If you want to flatten completely, but don't know how deep the nesting is,  `error_hash.flatten(1000000) #=> [:base, "Address is required to activate"]`, though not pretty, works.  You should remove all `[0]` and `[1]` labels so that readers can just cut and paste.

Comment: How can a question about flattening a hash be regarded as a duplicate of one that concerns the flattening of an array? If you agree, please consider voting to reopen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you expect flatten to act recursively when the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Hash.html) does suggest otherwise?

You can extend the capability of hash using following:

```
class Hash
  def flatten_deepest
    self.each_with_object({}) do |(key, val), h|
      if val.is_a? Hash
        val.flatten_to_root.map do |hash_key, hash_val|
          h["#{key}.#{hash_key}".to_sym] = hash_val
        end
      else
        h[k] = val
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and then do:

```
 error_hash.flatten_deepest
```

I think you got the idea.